# js sequelize nest queries / loop through results

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a first query where I get a list of objects looking like this:

```
{
   id
   idmarker
   idcategory
}

 MarkerCategories.findAll({where: {idmarker: data.dataValues.id}})
```

This would get me a resultset with the categoryIds belonging to the provided marker id.
How can I save the id properties of the resultset into an array named ids so I can run the following query to get the actual Category details:

```
 Categories.findAll({where: {id: { $in: ids}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already defined association between `Categories` and `Markers` models, you can just do the following:

```
 Markers.findAll({where: { id: markerId }, include: [ Categories ]})
```

that will return a Marker with a related Categories

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to setup the association with my current table structure: 

`markers { id, name }
categories { id, name } 
markers_categories { id, idmarker, idcategory}
`

However, I found the following solution in the meanwhile:
`return MarkerCategories.findAll({where: {idmarker: data.dataValues.id}}).then(function(data){
                var ids = new Array();
                data.map(item => ids.push(item.dataValues.idcategory));
                return Categories.findAll({where: {id: { $in: ids}}});
            });
`

Comment: Your solution will work, but it's a wrong way: it will execute 2 queries; size of the code; Right way is to define association and use includes as the code above. Your association will looks like this `Markers.belongsToMany(Categories, { through: MarkerCategories, foreignKey: idmarker, otherKey: idcategory });`. For more info see docs http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations